# Conservation of percent difference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, error-analysis, statics

I was doing a lab to experimentally determine coefficients of static friction between two surface. This was the basic set up:[image]

The mass of the block is a known quantity. I was checking the maximum mass M so that everything would hold still, along with the minimum mass to achieve this. Effectively, this is testing the pull of friction both down the ramp (max case) and up the ramp (min case).

The calculation was a simple sum of forces problem, When I ran the calculations (using an arbitrary precision calculator), the percent difference between both μ values (we'll call them μ1 and μ2) was 2.602% which was good enough. If we were going to use our data, we'd simply average theses two values and that would be good enough.

Then I had the idea to try something else. For the first case the sum of forces looked something like this:

$$\sum F = F_W - F_T - F_{fric}$$

The second case only differed in that friction was added rather than subtracted. If you take these two equations (from the first and second case) and add them together, the friction cancels out. If you pretend that the mass of the block on the ramp is unknown, you can solve for it. You'll get a slightly different mass (0.6521% off), and this makes sense. You can then plug this mass into the first style of calculation, solving for friction, and get the exact same μ to the umpteenth decimal. In theory, this value should be the average of μ1 and &mu2; considering how this formula was derived. It's actually 0.6521% off (the same difference as between the known and predicted masses).

My question has a few parts.

1. Why is there a discrepancy between the averaged μ from the first calculation and the second calculation?
2. If this difference is significant, which μ is more right (or rather reliable)?
3. If both calculations are valid, shouldn't they both yield the same percent difference? (hence conservation of percent difference)

Measurements:

```
Mass of block (measured): .375 kg
Mass of block (calculated): .3774kg
Mass of max weight: 0.170 kg
Mass of min weight: 0.057 kg
Angle of slope: 17.5
```

Comment: This question is mostly about measuring error, so you need to provide data on the replicates (if any) you performed. Also, explain the symbols you use: we are not mind readers! Ta.